# Custom Taxonomy WooCommerce Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

The Wordpress application I am currently working on is using WooCommerce as well as Tabify.

Most of the fields are defined as Custom Fields which I am able to get by adding `filter[meta]=true` in the query but there are two `Status` and `Region` which have been defined as Custom Taxonomies.

I have been looking for a way to get these data with the Rest API but with no luck so far.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you check the official [Woocommerce REST API](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) page? Also try asking on their [github](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce) pages

Comment: I did check the docs but I only found something about the custom fields. I am still looking for something about taxonomy. 

I'll try posting something on the GitHub page.

Comment: Can you please check http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/ this link? i think this link helpful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. Maybe it's not the most practical solution and it will have to be reapplied every time I update the WooCommerce plugin but just update the product API like this

```
private function get_product_data( $product ) {
    return array(
       // your other properties go here
       'region' => wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'productRegion', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ),
       'status' => wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'productActive', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ),
    )
}
```

Now I just access region[0] and status[0] from the response and do whatever I need to do with it.